# How to export an fbx from an imported obj using assimp

Tags: c++, fbx, assimp

I am creating my C++ game engine and I wanted to be able to export my scenes using the FBX format.

So, when I tried to export an FBX from a previously imported OBJ file, that actually renders correctly. But it is not exported correctly when exporting to anything other than what it was originally imported from.

```
std::unique_ptr<Assimp::Exporter> exporter = std::make_unique<Assimp::Exporter>();

const auto* scene = mesh->mScene;
exporter->Export(scene, "fbx", "assets/output.fbx");
```

Here, `mesh->mScene` is the `aiScene` imported previously.

This code actually works and `Export()` returns success; however, the output file does not include the proper data of the mesh. Only when imported from an FBX is it correct and can be imported in Maya without problems.

I need a way to convert `Assim::aiScene` to be exported in the FBX format, because `Assimp` only allows to export meshes to the same format as it is imported from.

Also, I wanted to be able to modify the meshes, let's say I want to replace the diffuse texture.

```
//Yeah, sorry I am still a beginner :)
auto* aiMaterial = mesh->mScene->mMaterials[index];


if (aiMaterial->RemoveProperty("$clr.diffuse") != 0 || aiMaterial->AddProperty(texture->getPath().c_str(), 1, "$clr.diffuse") != 0)
{
    assert(false, "Failed to add property!");
}
```

This code also runs fine but it does not change anything in the mesh.